# Twig escape filter strategy registration in Symfony 3 DI

Tags: php, symfony, twig, escaping, twig-filter

I need a custom escape strategy and I ended up reading this:
https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/escape.html#custom-escapers

It's very easy to understand, but I'm not sure how do I register such escaper using Symfony 3 DI container?

I'd love to share with you what I've done so far, but... I haven't done anything so far, besides creating a class and method that takes listed arguments (`twig env`, `string to escape` and `charset`) and returns "escaped" string (which is irrelevant to this question really).

How do I register it the "Symfony way"?

Answer (score 0):

These two links can help you. You have to create a twig extension.

- [How to write a custom extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html)
- [Register extension as a service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html#register-an-extension-as-a-service)

Comment: Well, I know how to write the extension, but I have no idea how to add escape strategy to escape filter (existing twig filter).

Comment: Oh I see I missunderstood your question. Unfortunately I haven't found a nice solution (e.g. define the escape strategy in global scope). But here you can find a different aproach. https://benoliver999.com/technology/2017/06/11/customescaper/

Comment: And you can see some arguments why to use own extension over custom escaper here https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/1689

Comment: Thanks! I already figured out the solution presented in first link, thought I may find a symfony / twig bridge "native" way of doing it. Well, I will stick to custom filter probably. Thanks. If you could update the answer with few words about the approach from first link and why custom filter is better I will accept this as an answer.